# Elasticsearch build failed on IntelliJ due to compilation error

Tags: debugging, elasticsearch, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-10

I'm trying to debug through the elasticsearch (version 6.6) source code on IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10 OS.

The build.gradle file has compile time errors. The following import statements are not being recognized and upon hovering over them, I see a message that says "Cannot resolve symbol (name)"

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowPlugin
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import org.elasticsearch.gradle.BuildPlugin
import org.elasticsearch.gradle.Version
import org.elasticsearch.gradle.VersionCollection
import org.elasticsearch.gradle.VersionProperties
import com.carrotsearch.gradle.junit4.RandomizedTestingTask
```

Here is my stack -

- Gradle: 6.2.2
- Kotlin: 1.3.61
- Groovy: 2.5.8
- Ant:    Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
- JVM:    11.0.6 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.6+8-LTS)
- OS:     10 10.0 amd64
- IntlliJ IDEA Community 2019.3

Comment: Please try to disable antivirus software

Comment: I turned off my 'Real-time protection' under Virus and threat protection settings and ran the same command, it gives the same error. I had also added exclusions to Windows Security for the gradle and elasticsearch folders earlier, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run command in command line outside IDE?

Comment: No, now I am getting a different error altogether. I have updated the information in the question please have a look

Comment: Please check this thread: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/if-your-plugin-build-breaks-when-upgrading-to-5-6/101752

Comment: The noticeFile and licenseFile are already specified in my build.gradle, however upon looking at my build.gradle file I realized it has compile time errors - it is unable to recognize the import statements. I have updated my question with these details, please have a look